# Does Bulletstorm's last cinematic not have a video?

Tags: bulletstorm

I've just finished Bulletstorm and in the last cinematic where there are two people talking (just after the space pod cinematic), all I saw was a black screen and some subtitles.

Is this a problem with the version I had or is this to be expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bulletstorm's last cinematic does not have a video. You saw it correctly. I assume you're talking about the post-game scene where

> Ishi turns out to be still alive, along with Saranno?

It's just a black screen, perhaps to build suspense, or perhaps also to

> not reveal the new cyborg models of Ishi and Sarrano.